# Updating the value of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
SELECT * FROM labels LIMIT 5;
 user_id | session_id |    start_timestamp     |     end_timestamp      | travelmode 
---------+------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------
      11 |          0 | 2007-06-26 12:32:29+01 | 2007-06-26 12:40:29+01 | bus
      11 |          0 | 2008-03-31 17:00:08+01 | 2008-03-31 17:09:01+01 | taxi
      11 |          0 | 2008-04-01 01:48:32+01 | 2008-04-01 01:59:23+01 | taxi
      11 |          0 | 2008-04-01 02:00:22+01 | 2008-04-01 02:08:13+01 | walk
      11 |          0 | 2008-04-01 12:22:47+01 | 2008-04-01 12:28:39+01 | taxi
(5 rows)

SELECT * FROM trajectories LIMIT 5;
 user_id |    session_id     |       timestamp        |    lat    |    lon     | alt  
---------+-------------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+------
      11 | 10020080330004134 | 2008-03-30 00:41:34+00 | 36.032647 | 103.850612 | -777
      11 | 10020080330004134 | 2008-03-30 00:42:05+00 | 36.031563 | 103.851273 | -777
      11 | 10020080330004134 | 2008-03-30 00:43:04+00 | 36.028623 | 103.853238 | -777
      11 | 10020080330004134 | 2008-03-30 00:44:03+00 | 36.027323 | 103.854475 | -777
      11 | 10020080330004134 | 2008-03-30 00:45:02+00 | 36.025775 | 103.854993 | -777
(5 rows)
```

So I want to update the `session_id` column of the `labels` table(initially all zero):

```
UPDATE labels
SET session_id=trajectories.session_id
FROM trajectories
WHERE 
  trajectories.user_id = labels.user_id
  AND trajectories.timestamp >= labels.start_timestamp 
  AND trajectories.timestamp <= labels.end_timestamp;

UPDATE 4500
```

However, not all columns of the `labels` table were updated (about 30% only) after about 5-minutes of query execution:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM labels WHERE session_id=0;
 count 
-------
 10217
(1 row)
```

If it might helps, more about the tables:

```
\d labels
                             Table "akil.labels"
     Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 user_id         | integer                  |           | not null | 
 session_id      | bigint                   |           |          | 
 start_timestamp | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 end_timestamp   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 travelmode      | text                     |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "mode_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id, start_timestamp, end_timestamp)

 \d trajectories 
                       Table "akil.trajectories"
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 user_id    | integer                  |           |          | 
 session_id | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 timestamp  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | 
 lat        | double precision         |           | not null | 
 lon        | double precision         |           | not null | 
 alt        | double precision         |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "trajectory_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (session_id, "timestamp", lat, lon)
```

**EDIT**

Adding index to `trajectories` table:

```
 CREATE INDEX idx_trecj ON trajectories (user_id, timestamp);
CREATE INDEX

UPDATE labels
SET session_id=trajectories.session_id
FROM trajectories
WHERE 
  trajectories.user_id = labels.user_id
  AND trajectories.timestamp >= labels.start_timestamp 
  AND trajectories.timestamp <= labels.end_timestamp;

UPDATE 4500

 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM labels WHERE session_id=0;
 count 
-------
 10217
(1 row
```

Yet, not all `session_id` in `labels` are updated (same as the initial operation).

**EDIT**

Result of queries from the answer by @Erwin (this shows many none):

```
SELECT count(*) AS no_match_in_trajectories
FROM   akil.labels l
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM akil.trajectories t
   WHERE  t.user_id   =  l.user_id
   AND    t.timestamp >= l.start_timestamp 
   AND    t.timestamp <= l.end_timestamp
   );
no_match_in_trajectories 
--------------------------
                    10217
(1 row)
```

In the second query (suggested way to do the update, none was updated);

```
UPDATE akil.labels l
SET    session_id = t.session_id
FROM   akil.labels l1
CROSS  JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT t1.session_id
   FROM   akil.trajectories t1
   WHERE  t1.user_id   =  l1.user_id
   AND    t1.timestamp >= l1.start_timestamp 
   AND    t1.timestamp <= l1.end_timestamp
   ORDER  BY t1.timestamp  -- pick the earliest matching entry
   LIMIT  1
   ) t
WHERE ( l.user_id,  l.start_timestamp,  l.end_timestamp)  -- PK
   =  (l1.user_id, l1.start_timestamp, l1.end_timestamp)
AND    l.session_id IS DISTINCT FROM t.session_id;

UPDATE 0
```

Comment: `session_id` is `initially all zero`. Yet there is no `NOT NULL` constraint. And no `DEFAULT 0`. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `search_path`

Your table definition reveals:

> Table "akil.labels"

So the table lives in schema `akil`. Is the `search_path` set correctly at all times, so that you can afford to omit schema qualification in your queries? Else, you might be updating the wrong table by accident / from the wrong table - which could explain your results. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

But there are other possible explanations.

#### No match in `akil.trajectories`

What makes you think there is an applicable row in `trajectories` for every row in `labels`?

This many have none:

```
SELECT count(*) AS no_match_in_trajectories
FROM   akil.labels l
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM akil.trajectories t
   WHERE  t.user_id   =  l.user_id
   AND    t.timestamp >= l.start_timestamp 
   AND    t.timestamp <= l.end_timestamp
   );
```

#### Multiple matches in `akil.trajectories`

On a related note: What makes you think there would be *exactly one* applicable row? Your `UPDATE` produces arbitrary results (in an expensive way) if there are more than one applicable rows in `trajectories`.

Given your table definitions, this would be a proper way to do it:

```
UPDATE akil.labels l
SET    session_id = t.session_id
FROM   akil.labels l1
CROSS  JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT t1.session_id
   FROM   akil.trajectories t1
   WHERE  t1.user_id   =  l1.user_id
   AND    t1.timestamp >= l1.start_timestamp 
   AND    t1.timestamp <= l1.end_timestamp
   ORDER  BY t.timestamp  -- pick the earliest matching entry
   LIMIT  1
   ) t
WHERE ( l.user_id,  l.start_timestamp,  l.end_timestamp)  -- PK
   =  (l1.user_id, l1.start_timestamp, l1.end_timestamp)
AND    l.session_id IS DISTINCT FROM t.session_id;        -- avoids empty updates
```

About avoidable empty updates:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

The perfect index for this would be:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON akil.trajectories (user_id, timestamp) INCLUDE (session_id)
```

[`INCLUDE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) requires Postgres 11 or later.

#### Asides

Your whole setup looks suspiciously messy.

- `mode_pkey` is the name of `labels` PK column. Quite misleading, table seems to have been renamed? Or is something off there?
- The PK of `trajectories`:

  ```
  "trajectory_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (session_id, "timestamp", lat, lon)
  ```

  Again, non-default name. A PK spanning 4 columns is suspicious to begin with. And `lat` and `lon` are floating point numbers. That's inviting duplicates with rounding errors, leading to all kinds of confusion.
- Like I commented: If `session_id` is `"initially all zero"`, the column should probably be `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`.

Comment: **Asides:** In the case of `mode_pkey`, yes I renamed table `mode` to `labels`

Comment: 10217 of 10217 remainig rows have no match. What's still unclear about `UPDATE 0`?

Answer (score -1):

For `trajectories`, you want an index on `(user_id, timestamp)`.

That should help your performance.

You also have an issue that there might be multiple matches.  If that is the case, your current `update` has to do much more work than necessary.  But the index should be a good first step.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, Whatever I have read is, Indexes on tables slows down the DML operations. Isn't it true always?

Comment: Created an index on `trajectories` table and repeated the `UPDATE` operation, same result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . There is a small overhead in maintaining the index when the data changes.  However, your `update` doesn't even affect the columns in the suggested index, so nothing needs to be done.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In PostgreSQL *all* indexes get modified, because a new row version is created. That is, unless you get a HOT update.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . I thought Postgres checked the version of the row when the index was used.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Each row version has its own index entry. Different versions of the same row are not connected in any way.